# Return a tns:QueryResult

Tags: soap-api, query, php

As someone new to salesforce I have been struggling.

I have this in my WSDL.

```
<element name="Device_Paths__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
```

in my `<complexType name="All_Device__c">`

I know if it was type string I could just do something like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT Device_Paths__r from All_Device__c WHERE OwnerAccount__r.Name='AlexUnited'limit 5000";
```

then in a for loop print like this:

```
print_r($record);
```

(Assuming the record is the query result).

However I am unsure how to get the info out of it because it is type tns:QueryResult. It just says

```
 No such column 'Device_Paths__r' on entity 'All_Device__c'
```

It cant seem to even identify the column and I am at a complete loss on how to get the info contained in it returned to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Device_Paths__r` is a relationship not a concrete field.

If it is a lookup relationship, the in a query within salesforce it would be used as follows

```
[Select Device_Paths__r.Name, Device_Paths__r.[SomeOtherField] From All_Device__c]
```

If it is a lookup relationship the field would be referenced as `Device_Paths__c`

It Could also be a child relationship name  used as follows:

```
[Select Id, (Select Name, [OtherFields] From Device_Paths__r) From All_Device__c]
```

Since the type is `QueryResult` I suspect it is the latter. I am not the best at WSDL types

After all the connection stuff I did the following in php to get the value of FirstName not he contact record.

```
$query = 'SELECT Id,Name, (Select FirstName, LastName From Contacts) from Account';
$response = $mySforceConnection->query(($query));
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    print_r($record);
    print_r("<br>");
    print_r($record->Contacts->records[0]->FirstName);
  }
```

> stdClass Object ( [Id] => 00136000009b257AAA [Contacts] => stdClass Object ( [done] => 1 [queryLocator] => [records] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => [FirstName] => Edna [LastName] => Frank ) ) [size] => 1 ) [Name] => GenePoint )
>
> Edna

If you get that working then you can start replacing object and field names to your custom objects and get it working. The above shows you that it works. If you are not getting expected results then first query in the SF Developer console to ensure you should actually be getting records back. Make sure permissions for the logged in user have access to the object. etc.

Comment: First one doesnt work, the second gets me this: stdClass Object ( [Id] => a0W60000004oVkjEAE ) which is at least returnign the object, but not what I am looking for.. The Paths on salesforce, it shows as a row with columns of: ID, Name, ESN, Device. Ideally would like to be able to grab the name of the path.

Comment: You have to get the inner array. And make sure you are querying for name etc on the inner query

Comment: I do realize, just unsure how to do it. Could not find examples for this online. I found the ones you posted, directly from the their examples, however I don't know how to get past that point. Tried things like Id.Name, or Id[Name] with no luck, unsure how to grab the name from the inner array.

Comment: @Lain - Give me a few minutes. I will work up an example using standard objects an PHP (maybe)

Comment: That would be great. I am coding this in PHP for my site.

Comment: @Lain - See updated answer

Comment: @Lain did you solve your issue

Comment: No, sorry. Was able to print name, but the name was actually the ESN  of the device, and not the name. Couldnt figure out what the name category would be called. Currently was told to put project on break anyways though. If you know how to get the other categories (Like how you got ID,name) that would be helpful for future though.

Comment: @Lain if name was the esn number then you will have to work with their sf admin to determine which field the store the device name in. You need to understand the esn object was built by the customer and only name and Id are standard fields so.

Answer (score 1):

```
<element name="Device_Paths__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
```

of `<complexType name="All_Device__c">` means `All_Device__c` object has child object with relationship with a name `Device_Paths__r` and child object could be `Device_Path`.

Retrieve the child records like this:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT Id FROM Device_Paths__r) from All_Device__c WHERE OwnerAccount__r.Name='AlexUnited'limit 5000"
```

Comment: This returns stdClass Object ( [Id] => a0W60000004oVkjEAE ), however on salesforce the Paths has several columns, name, device, ESN, etc. I would ideally like to grab the name, but dont know how to access this part from grabbing the object ID.